# How can I get all keys and assign to new common variable?

Tags: json, apache-nifi, jolt

I need some help with this jolt transformation.

Input:

```json
{
  "product": "monitor",
  "ID": "222",
  "price": "300"
}
```

expected output:

```json
{
  "product": "monitor",
  "ID": "222",
  "price": "300",
   "keys": ["product","ID","price"]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use **$** wildcard along with **@** wildcard within a **shift** transformation such as

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "@": "&",
        "$": "keys"
      }
    }
  }
]
```

the demo on the site http://jolt-demo.appspot.com/ is

[image]